# Run PHP script on the server to send notifications to android/iphone on regular intervals

Tags: php, android, iphone, notifications, background-process

I am using code-igniter framework for my PHP-angular project.I am looking run a php script, which will run on regular intervals and sends push notifications to all the users on phone, based on the database query.

Could someone help me on how can I approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You could set up a cronjob.

Comment: This question is too general - you need to be asking about specific issues you've got with code or your setup. Break this question up into parts and ask them one at a time, or search for tutorials on similar projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cronjob to schedule notifications. You can access all code-igniter controller methods via the command line.